# Is it possible to handle tap events in an InfoWindow in google_maps_flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm adding markers to a google map using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) and I want to display a new screen when an user taps the InfoTextWindow.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this. Does anyone have any idea?

The way I add a marker is:

```
mapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
        position: LatLng(sr.lat, sr.lon),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        infoWindowText: InfoWindowText(
          sr.serviceName,
          sr.description,
        ),
      ));
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't possible at the moment.

Comment: I found the fix. Look at my answer below.

Comment: I thought that you wanted to know specificly which marker was tapped. I believe that your solution will trigger for any tapped marker.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You can store your markers in a `Map<String, YourObject>` and then check if the id of `Marker` in `.onInfoWindowTapped(Marker marker` matches the one you're looking for.

Comment: That’s good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now a new way to do this, basically you should implement the `onTap` in your `InfoWindow` implementation. See this example:

```
Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId("your marker id"),
    position: position,
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    onTap: _onMarkerTapped,
    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: t.name,
        onTap: () {
           // InfoWindow clicked
        })
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the correct answer for people to see.

Comment: NOT working for ANDROID!

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that this is already implemented using `GoogleMapController.onInfoWindowTapped()`.